# Why does the behaviour of find(1) differ when explicitly adding -print?

Tags: linux, find, gnu

The man page for `find(1)` says:

> If the expression contains no actions other than `-prune`, `-print` is performed  on  all  files for which the expression is true.

However, there seems to be a difference between these two expressions:

```
$ find . -path '*fo*' -prune -o -type f -print
./bar/xzyzzy
$ find . -path '*fo*' -prune -o -type f
./foo
./bar/xzyzzy
```

Why is `./foo` included in the output of the latter?

I created the example directory tree structure for the above with:

```
$ cd $(mktemp -d)
$ mkdir foo
$ mkdir bar
$ touch foo/quux
$ touch bar/xzyzzy
```

The output of `find --version` for me is:

```
find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2`
```

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I think I've worked it out on my own...

In the former case, the `-print` is performed *only* when the first condition (`-path '*fo*'`) is not true because of the short-circuit behaviour of `-o`.

However, in the second case, the implicit `-print` is done when the *whole* expression is true - that will be the case when `-path '*fo*'` is true *or* `-type f` is true.  In other words, the two commands in my question are equivalent to:

```
$ find . \( -path '*fo*' -prune \) -o \( -type f -print \)
./bar/xzyzzy
```

... and:

```
$ find . \( -path '*fo*' -prune -o -type f \) -print
./foo
./bar/xzyzzy
```

I think, anyway :)